# rails cannot pass nested hash to controller params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, parameters, controller

Since I am using `Rspec` to test whether my controller is working fine, I did things below:

in test_rspec.rb,

```
before do
  params = {
    date_begin: "2018-10-01", 
    date_end: "2018-10-05", 
    options: {country_code: "US"}
  }

  get :index, params: params, as: :json
end

it do
  expected(response).to have_http_response(200) }
end
```

in test_controller.rb,

```
def index
  puts params_checker
  render json: Test.report(params_checker[:date_begin], 
                           params_checker[:date_end],
                           params_checker[:options])
end

private
  def params_checker
    params.permit(:date_begin, :date_end, :options)
  end
```

when I run code with `rspec` command, there goes something wrong, the parameter with nested hash `:options` is gone! below is the output of params in terminal & some of its error info:

```
> {"date_begin"=>"2018-10-01", "date_end"=>"2018-10-03"}
> ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

I search everywhere on internet and tried some of the solutions but it won`t help. I do know this error is caused by parameter missing. Could any one help me finger it out why hashes cannot be passed to controller`s params in my case?

`note`: I am using `rails 5.1.6`

Comment: 1) Change `options={country_code: "US"}` to `options: {country_code: "US"}`     
2) `Test.report` receives only 2 arguments, you are passing 3

Comment: @chumakoff after I change options to `options: {country_code: "US"}.to_s` and in controller `eval(params[:options])` it worked fine. but this is not a really good way to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You just created another problem! It must be like this: `params.permit(:date_begin, :date_end, options: [:country_code])` and without `.to_s`

Comment: @chumakoff please see the answer below, method in comment was a temporary solution and now I replaced it with which in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for lots of solutions, I got one clear way to handle it. [Strong parameters handling](https://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html) helped me a lot.

First, if you want to pass an array or hash, whatever the parameter is, only if it is a nested parameter, you should claim it inside the `params.permit()` statement, and add what key is allowed to pass in `[]`, *because `permit` only allows scalar values to pass, and filter hashes and arrays by default if the specific parameter is not claimed.* code as below:

```
private
  def stat_params
    params.permit(:date_begin, :date_end, options: [:country_code])
  end
```

Second, when using `Rspec` to test the controller, nested parameters will be passed as `<ActionController::Parameters:xxxx>`type, so you have to add `to_unsafe_h` statement to this specific parameter, as below:

```
def index
  render json: Test.report(stat_params[:date_begin],
                           stat_params[:date_end],
                           stat_params[:options].to_unsafe_h)
end
```

This works fine for me finally.